# Use of std::move in std::accumulate

Tags: c++, move-semantics, stdmove

In my Fedora 34 environment (g++), `std::accumulate` is defined as:

```
template<typename ITER, typename T>
constexpr inline T accumulate(ITER first, ITER last, T init)
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
      init = std::move(init) + *first; // why move ?

  return init;
}
```

If the expression `init + *first` is already an rvalue, what is the purpose of `std::move` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`std::move(init) + *first` can sometimes generate more efficient code than `init + *first`, because it allows `init` to be overwritten. However, since (as you observed) the result of the `+` will generally be an rvalue, there is no need to wrap the entire expression in a second `std::move`.

For example, if you are accumulating `std::string`s, then `std::move(init) + *first` might be able to append `*first` into reserved-but-not-yet-used space in `init`'s buffer instead of having to allocate a new buffer whose length is the sum of the lengths of `init` and `*first`.

Comment: Interesting though that it's defined using `+`, instead `init += *first;`, shouldn't that yield similar performance to the version with move? Is there really a valid case to prefer `+` and `move` over `+=` or is it just a design decision?

Comment: @alagner `std::accumulate` can't use `+=`, because it can't guarantee that `a += b` necessarily has the same semantics as `a = a + b` given that the user can overload these operators however they wish. If you want to write your own version with `+=`, that is a fine choice but you need to document it. If you're writing a non-generic version that just works with `std::string`, then you probably won't use `+` or `+=` at all since there are more efficient approaches to concatenation.

Comment: @BrianBi That's a "Doctor, it hurts if I do this" problem. If a user defines `operator +=` to have different semantics from `a=a+b` they get what they deserve.

Comment: @Spencer pretend that there's one overload and `BinaryOperation` is defaulted to `std::plus` if there were `std::plus_assign` we might have a different `std::accumulate`

Comment: @Caleth That's a _much_ better argument. Perhaps even an answer.

Comment: It's really the same argument. STL algorithms (and their descendants in the C++ std::lib) are specified in terms of the minimal operations they require, and for this algo the required operations are only `+` and assignment. Requiring `+=` would be a different set of requirements, so a different algorithm that would not be usable with types that only provide `+` and not `+=`. tl;dr the algorithm _as specified for decades_ doesn't even assume that `a += b` exists for the type. Changing it to use `+=` instead would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 22):

The value category of `init + *first` doesn't matter.

`init` in `init + *first` is a lvalue.

So if `init + *first` calls an `operator+` overload taking the parameter by-value, it will cause a copy construction of that parameter

But the value of `init` is not required anymore after `init + *first`, so it makes sense to move it into the parameter instead.

Similarly a `operator+` overload taking its first argument by rvalue-reference might be used to allow modification of the argument by the operation.

This is what `std::move` achieves here.

The standard specifies this behavior since C++20.

Comment: But the `operator +` undoes any of this effect. It's going to return a pure rvalue which will be copied.

Comment: @Spencer If `operator+` returns by-value, then `std::move(init) + *first` is a prvalue expression (independently of the `std::move`) and `=` will therefore use move assignment if available for the type. In the end, only moves are required, no copies.

Answer (score 6):

It's nothing to do with the return value of `operator +`, but with the arguments to it.

As far as I can tell, a valid implementation of `std::accumulate` could be

```
template<typename ITER, typename T, typename OP = plus>
constexpr inline T accumulate(ITER first, ITER last, T init, OP op = {})
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
      init = op(std::move(init), *first); // move the argument that is being overwritten

  return init;
}
```

It would be a larger breaking change to specify `accumulate` in terms of `operator +=`. For symmetry you'd want to change the *BinaryOperation* overloads, and that would break all the existing uses, as would any type that defined `+` but not `+=` .

Answer (score -2):

I was just reminded, when I wrote out an example of bignum addition yesterday as a lesson, why this is more efficient.

The binary `+` operator creates and returns a temporary object.  With operands that fit into a machine register, this can be zero-cost (at most spilling what was in the destination register before onto the stack), but sometimes, a large data structure will need to be created.  And this seems to be template code that might have to implement that use case.

If the left operand can be clobbered, though, `+` can be implemented as `+=`, overwriting the operand and optimizing away the creation of a new copy.

This coding style strikes me as a bit odd—as I mentioned, `+=` has exactly the semantics the programmer seems to want here, so I’m not sure why they don’t use that instead.

Comment: @YSC I’ve removed the misleading sentence.

Comment: Since the comments have been cleaned up, the reason for the downvotes is that I originally referred to an expandable template argument as a “macro.” In C++, that term normally only is used for preprocessor macros

Comment: You're assuming the type even has `+=`, which is an assumption that this algorithm doesn't make. One of Stepanov's goals for the STL was to define things in terms of the minimal set of operations required. Even if `+=` exists, assuming that `a += b`  has the same semantics as `a = a + b` would be another additional requirement that the algo would need to document.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The implementation might check for `+=` with a `requires` clause or a `concept`. You’re correct that it might break on a type that overloads `operator+=` with different semantics. Although I could also think of types for which this version would break, such as a type that can be updated but not assigned to.

Comment: @JonathanWakely However, you have a good point that the Standard Library defines how this function works, and making assumptions about `+=` (if present) would complicate that in an undesirable way. A modern implementation should really take an arbitrary reduction function, defaulting to `std::plus<T>`, though. In practice, any well-behaved type will implement `operator+(T&&, const T&)` to have the same behavior as `operator+=` if it matters, and then check for self-assignment. Using `+=` would, therefore optimize out the tuntime self-assignment test.